# Mod rewrite - Change url parameters to absolute url on centos

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos

My host says everything is good with mod-rewrite but this simple rewrite rule doesn't work. Is my rule not right? I'm trying to have an absolute url perform the action of a querystring.

To run this:

```
 http://www.blah.com/thinking-big/view/?title=foo
```

I want this url to be in the addressbar:

```
http://www.blah.com/thinking-big/foo
```

Here's my rule:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/thinking-big/(.*)$ /thinking-big/view/index.php?title=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/` is ignored in the rewriterule at the beginnging of the `URI` so it will not ever match. Try it this way.

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^thinking-big/(.*)$ /thinking-big/view/index.php?title=$1
```

Comment: hmm, same problem. It doesn't go to the right page. When I enter: http://www.blah.com/thinking-big/foo It just goes to the thinking-big/ index page.

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try it again. Also is foo a real dir or not?

Comment: foo would be the value of an ID which queries the database in php

Comment: Ok then what I have should work. Are you sure modrewrite is on? Or that your htaccess is allowed? Add some random text at the top of your .htaccess file. If you don't get an internal server error. Then the server is probably not reading your .htaccess file.